# How do I add burger menu to Xamarin iOS project?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I need to add a menu to a Xamarin iOS project.

I have a page (viewController). It's the home page and I need to add the menu on this page.

Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: It's worth noting that iOS favour the 'TabBar' over the UWP preferered 'Hamburger' menu. So maybe take a look at the UITabViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this without having to use any third party library

[Hamburger menu in xamarin iOS](https://xamarinexperience.blogspot.com/2019/02/hamburger-menu-in-xamarin-ios.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Xamarin.SideMenu: https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.SideMenu

There is also some library available in the Xamarin Component Store (Sidebar Navigation, SlideMenuController, ...)

Alternatively, you can code your own. Here is some tutorials about how to do it (it is in Obj-C/Swift, but you can translate it to C# easily):

https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/
https://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path
https://www.thorntech.com/2016/03/ios-tutorial-make-interactive-slide-menu-swift/

Comment: i don't have knowledge in swift :(